# if condition depending on which text the class is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a condition depending on which li text the class is. I have a menu that will assign a class depending on which li is selected.

**HTML** *Room description* is selected so class *active* is showing up

```
<div class="vmenu" style="position: relative; top: 42px;">
<ul>
<li class="active">
<span>Room description</span>
</li>
<li class="sep"> </li>
<li>
<span>Room Amenities</span>
</li>
```

**jquery**

```
var package = $(".detail-layer.package-detail-layer")
var active = $(".active").text()

if($('#tbLayerDiv').css('display') == 'block')
{
  if (active == "Room description")
  {
  //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: use $(selector).hasClass().

Comment: Depending on an index, or in other words the position in the DOM, or a data attribute etc. is generally safer than depending on random case-sensitive text.

Comment: You are better off using a data attribute than the text.

Answer (score 0):

`active` will contain newlines because of the line breaks between `<li>` and `<span>`, so it won't match `Room description`. You could use `.trim()` to remove the whitespace:

```
var active = $(".active").text().trim();
```

Or you could get the text from the span:

```
var active = $(".active span").text();
```

But it would be better to use an attribute in the element itself to recognize the selected menu item.

```
<li class="active" data-name="room-desc">
```

Then you can do:

```
var active = $(".active").data("name");
```

and later:

```
if (active == "room-desc")
```

This way you can change the wording in your text without having to rewrite code (imagine if a user asks Google Translate to translate the site, it would break your script).

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/94xw513j/

```
<div class="vmenu" style="position: relative; top: 42px;">
<ul>
<li data-val='1'>
<span>Room description</span>
</li>
<li class="sep"> </li>
<li data-val='2'>
<span>Room Amenities</span>
</li>



$("ul li").on('click', function(event) { 
    $(this).parents("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    switch(eval($(this).data("val")))
    {
        case 1: // room description
        case 2: // room amenities
            alert($(this).text() + ' is active ');
            break;
    }

});
```